# Automatically paste commands in multiple processes of a screen session

Tags: bash, shell-script, gnu-screen

I have several bunch of commands writen in bash contained in a text file, separated by `\n\n` and I would like to automatically paste each in given screen processes. For the sake of clarity, let's say my `command.txt` simply contains :

```
#first bunch of commands:    
executable_script1.sh
mv executable_script1 directory1


#second bunch of commands:    
executable_script2.sh
mv executable_script2 directory2
```

So the first bunch of commands would run `executable_script1.sh`, after what it will move `executable_script1`. In this example, my screen contains 3 processes:

```
0$ htop
1$ bash
2$ bash
```

The name of the processes is irrelevant, the only important information is that I would like commands `N` in screen process `N$`, as `0$` is always a `htop`.

As for now, I have been copying/pasting manually each bunch of commands in the corresponding screen processes, which worked obviously, but now I will be dealing with more than 40 bunch of commands and as many screen processes. So, how could I paste the commands `N` to the `N$` screen terminal automatically? I think a `bash`/`shell` script could do the trick, but I am not fluent enough with it. Mind that I could create one `txt` file by bunch of commands if needed.

Could you help me with this? Please feel free to ask for any missing information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my answer, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064548/send-commands-to-a-gnu-screen?rq=1) on StackExchange! Sometimes it just takes some other keywords to find a solution, so I will answer this question in case some other fellows end up here.

### In a nutshell

Automatically paste commands in the screen with the `bash` command :

```
screen -x screen_name -p 1 -S stuff 'executable_script1.sh\n'
```

where `-p 1` refers to the `1$` screen process. Note that `\n` at the end of the command is necessary, as when you press enter after pasting a command line.

### Detailed steps

1) Create the `screen` session you want to work in (here named 'screen_name') :

```
screen -S screen_name
```

with enough processes for all the commands (in my example, `0$ htop` plus 2 processes : `1$` and `2$`). Note that you can edit `.screenrc` in your home directory so that screen sessions start with a given number of processes by default. For this example, my `.screenrc` contains :

```
screen -t htop
screen -t 
screen -t
```

2) Create bash files for every bunch of commands, to be executed by the different screen processes.

Here I have 2 files, `screen1` containing :

```
#!/bin/bash

screen -x screen_name -p 1 -X stuff 'executable_script1.sh\n'
screen -x screen_name -p 1 -X stuff 'mv executable_script1 directory1\n'
```

and `screen2` containing :

```
#!/bin/bash

screen -x screen_name -p 2 -X stuff 'executable_script2.sh\n'
screen -x screen_name -p 2 -X stuff 'mv executable_script2 directory1\n'
```

3) Paste all your commands at once in a terminal, with :

```
bash /path_to_screen1/screen1 & /path_to_screen1/screen2 &
```

You can close this terminal immediately, even if you have long run calculations, as all it does is paste the command into `screen`. Manually open your `screen` session to verify that these lines are being executed.

Needless to say, if you have a great number of commands to pass to many screen processes, you can create the bash files and paste the commands (steps 2 and 3) via a script (with `python`for instance). Also `executable_script1.sh` can contain `python` calls if needed, with `python python_script.py`, as in a normal terminal.

Hope this will help others!